# video duration inside a for loop not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

the code is taken from the following link :https://s3.amazonaws.com/demo.jwplayer.com/text-tracks/chapters.html
in the code there is the following:

```
  function update() {
    var p = v.currentTime/v.duration*100;
    b.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, #500 "+p+"%, #000 "+p+"%)";
  }

  function render() {
    var c = v.textTracks[0].cues;
    for (var i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
      var s = document.createElement("span");
      s.innerHTML = c[i].text;
      s.setAttribute('data-start',c[i].startTime);
      s.style.width = ((c[i].endTime-c[i].startTime)/888*480-7)+'px';
      s.addEventListener("click",seek);
      b.appendChild(s);
    }
  }
```

in the `render()` function. the number 888 represent the full duration of the video. Is there anyway that I can retrieve the full duration automatically? 
in the `update()` function there is a variable v.duration. I tried to use it instead of the 888 but the code still did not work. what is the reason v.duration did not work in the `render()` function? is there an easy fix?

---------------------[EDIT]-----------------------

I have noticed that v.duration does not work in Chrome only.. and the value of v.duration from Chrome is "NaN". 
Things to note:
I am using local HTML files with local HTML videos on my computer. 
I am using --allow-file-access-from-files when running chrome so I can load local captions and video.

Comment: declare a global variable `= v.duration` (outside both functions) and use it instead.

Comment: @sideroxylon a global variable is already declared. see the link for the full source

Comment: I would like to mention that when I call the v.duration variable.. I get "NaN". which means not a number!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement says about `duration`: _“If the media data is available but the length is unknown, this value is `NaN`.”_ – that’s most likely the case here, the duration is simply not available yet at the point when `render` is called. Perhaps try calling it on a different event – [`loadedmetadata`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CBroe comment made me solve the problem:
instead of

```
  v.addEventListener('click',play,false);
  v.addEventListener('timeupdate',update,false);
  t.addEventListener('loaded',render,false); // Bug in FF31 MAC: wrong event name
  t.addEventListener('load',render,false);
```

use

```
  v.addEventListener('click',play,false);
  v.addEventListener('timeupdate',update,false);
  t.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',render,false);
```